# extract CSS from js component with webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am using React and splitting CSS with each Component.
and I want to extract CSS from these files.

```
// ComponentA.js
import "./ComponentA.css"
export default class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    ...
}

// ComponentB.js
import "./ComponentB.css"
export default class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    ...
}

// index.js
import ComponentA from "./ComponentA"
import ComponentB from "./ComponentB"
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentA />
                <ComponentB />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

in this case, how can i extract and bundle `ComponentA.css` and `ComponentB.css`

without transpile whole JS sources?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `extract-text-plugin` to do this. It will bundle your css to one file.

[read more about this plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

Comment: I'm using `extract-text-plugin` in other build. but it works only with babel, cause css is imported from JS source. Is there any possible way to use `extract-text-plugin` without babel?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Comment: There is also an extract function on the instance. You should use this if you have more than one instance of ExtractTextPlugin.

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// Create multiple instances
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-one.css');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-two.css');